# JavaScript timing events with setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to use seTimeout() to fade out and then back in a `<div>` element while the page is scrolling. `fadeOut()` works as intended but `fadeIn()` only ever gets to 0.1 opacity.

It seems as if the opacity of the `<div>` element is set to 0 constantly and when I call fade in, it only bumps it up to .1 before it is reset back to 0.. That's my theory at least and since I'm new to JS I am having issues figuring this out.

**Code:**

```
function fadeOut() {
    console.log("fade out: " + document.getElementById('quotes').style.opacity)
    if(document.getElementById('quotes').style.opacity > .11) {
        document.getElementById('quotes').style.opacity -= .1;
        fadeDelay = setTimeout('fadeOut()',100);
    } else {
        document.getElementById('quotes').style.opacity = 0;
        console.log("stopped fade out.");
    }
}

function fadeIn() {
    console.log("fade in: " + document.getElementById('quotes').style.opacity)
    if(document.getElementById('quotes').style.opacity < .9) {
        document.getElementById('quotes').style.opacity += .1;
        fadeDelay = setTimeout('fadeIn()',100);
    } else {
        document.getElementById('quotes').style.opacity = 1;
        console.log("stopped fade in.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your code demonstrating the problem? How is `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` originally called? What does the HTML look like?

Comment: If you have jQuery, have you tried [fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a weird and uncommon way to fade a dom element. I'd recommend you to switch your approach using [requestAnimationFrame](http://css-tricks.com/using-requestanimationframe/) or using [pure css](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp).

In this case, using css you be the quickest, lightest and easiest way of doing things. You would then have something like this:

**CSS**

```
#quotes {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

**JS**

```
var quotes = document.getElementById("quotes");

function fadeIn() {
    quotes.style.opacity = 1;
}

 function fadeOut() {
    quotes.style.opacity = 0;
}
```

It's up to you to play with timings and curves to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

style.opacity returns a string, += contacts the string instead of increasing the value

try this

```
function fadeIn() {
console.log("fade in: " + document.getElementById('quotes').style.opacity)
var opacity = Number(document.getElementById('quotes').style.opacity)
if(document.getElementById('quotes').style.opacity < 0.9) {
    document.getElementById('quotes').style.opacity = opacity + 0.1;
    fadeDelay = setTimeout('fadeIn()',100);
} else {
    document.getElementById('quotes').style.opacity = 1;
    console.log("stopped fade in.");
}
}
```